# Google Query, change select columns based on cell reference?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am trying to improve a manual process that requires filtering through the input from a Google Form. It would be great if we could filter each question individually, without building multiple queries.

What I am looking for is as follows:

If I enter "A" in Cell A1, the query would execute the equivalent of:

```
=QUERY(Responses,"Select A where A IS NOT NULL",1)
```

But if I enter "B" in Cell A1, the query would execute the equivalent of:

```
=QUERY(Responses,"Select B where B IS NOT NULL",1)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
=QUERY(Responses,"Select " &A1& " where " &A1& " IS NOT NULL",1)
```

make sure that your A1 cell is uppercase, otherwise this will not work.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much!